# Change npm registry by project

Tags: npm

Is it possible to set registry for a specific project only.

I've installed verdaccio for publishing private enterprise modules. 
I'd like to not use systematically this registry for other projects.

Each time i switch project i have to reset the registry manually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, set in your `package.json` this using your `verdaccio` domain.

```
  "publishConfig": {
     "registry": "http:///localhost:4873"
   },
```